# Installer waiting when EXE is run as custom action during installation

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action, mosquitto, wix3.10

I am installing Mosquitto using WIX and once the files are copied I'm trying to run the mosquitto.exe using a custom action. It launches a new command prompt and the installation pauses there. It resumes only when I terminate that command prompt. Below is my code.

```
<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="MosquittoInstaller" Level="1">
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="MosquittoFilesGroup"/>
    </Feature>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="RunMosquitto" Before="InstallFinalize" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>


  <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION">
    <Directory Id="KubeInstallDir" Name="Kube2.0">
      <Directory Id="MyProgramDir" Name="Mosquitto" />
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
<CustomAction Id='RunMosquitto'  FileKey="fil7D28AEF774656849395A2FA20A5C963D"  Execute="deferred" ExeCommand='-v' Return="check" HideTarget="no" Impersonate="no"/>
```

What am I doing wrong here? Please advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The installation pauses because in your custom action, you have `Return="check"`. See the [CustomAction documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/customaction.html) for more information regarding the Return attribute.

`Return="asyncNoWait"` is what you want.

However, [the WiX documentation for running a program after install](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/run_program_after_install.html) shows a different way:

```
<Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#myapplication.exe]" />
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="yes" />
```

Comment: Regarding the second approach you mentioned, can you tell me how I can pass the argument to the installer? I will specify "mosquitto.exe" in Value section under Property. But what about the argument "-v" ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. I would try something like `Value="[#myapplication.exe] -v"` or `Value='"[#myapplication.exe]" -v'` and see how it behaves.

Comment: Sorry @mayooran looks like I steered you wrong earlier. I guess the correct way to use command line parameters is to us a standard custom action as you were.